# Integral $\int\frac{4x^4}{{x^8+1}}\;dx$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, rational-functions

I'm attempting this integral but I'm unsure how to proceed. I've begun to suspect it's actually non-elementary. Can anyone do this? I could always use Taylor series after a small bit of u-sub and integration by parts, but I wanted to know if there were a somewhat more direct way of doing it.
 The integral is $$\int\frac{4x^4}{{x^8+1}}\;dx$$
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rational functions always have elementary antiderivatives. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+4x%5E4%2F%28x%5E8%2B1%29dx

Comment: That integral is a nightmare...but its primitive function can be expressed in terms of a finite numbers of elemnetary functions and sum, multiplication and etc. But it seems to have around 10 (or  more) very, very ugly terms, including hyperbolic and inverse hyperbolic functions , lots of trigonometric ones, logarithms and etc.

Comment: @DonAntonio. It is not so bad. I worked one step at the time and combined the logarithms and the arctangents. I hope and wish you are OK, my friend. Take care. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, let me precise that, for this kind of integrals, Taylor expansions could me more thatn dangerous.

Considering the integrand, you can first write (by analogy with $(x^4+1)$
$$\frac {4x^4}{x^8+1}=\frac{\sqrt{2} x^2}{x^4-\sqrt{2} x^2+1}-\frac{\sqrt{2} x^2}{x^4+\sqrt{2} x^2+1}$$
Then
$$x^4-\sqrt{2} x^2+1=\left(x^2-\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \left(x^2-\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$
$$x^4+\sqrt{2} x^2+1=\left(x^2+\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \left(x^2+\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$ which finally make
$$\frac {4x^4}{x^8+1}=\frac{i \sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}-(1-i) x^2}-\frac{i \sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}-(1+i) x^2}+\frac{i \sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}+(1-i) x^2}-\frac{i \sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}+(1+i) x^2}$$ and now, we face quite trivial integrals.
$$\int\frac {4x^4}{x^8+1}\,dx=\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right) \left(\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{x^2+2 x \sin
   \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)+1}{x^2-2 x \sin \left(\frac{\pi
   }{8}\right)+1}\right)+\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 x \sin \left(\frac{\pi
   }{8}\right)}{1-x^2}\right)\right)+$$
$$\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right) \left(\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{x^2-2 x \cos
   \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)+1}{x^2+2 x \cos \left(\frac{\pi
   }{8}\right)+1}\right)-\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 x \cos \left(\frac{\pi
   }{8}\right)}{1-x^2}\right)\right)$$

In particular
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{4x^4}{{x^8+1}}\;dx=\pi\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} $$

Comment: Wow thanks. How did you get the integral from zero to infinity?

Comment: @superare496. Just apply the formula !

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer.  Maybe this result inspires a by-hand method.  The integral **is** "elementary".

\begin{align*}
&\int \frac{4x^4}{x^8+1} \,\mathrm{d}x  \\
&= 4 \left(-\frac{1}{8} \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right) \log \left(x^2-2 x \sin
   \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)+1\right)  
\right.  \\  &\quad \left. {}
+\frac{1}{8} \cos \left(\frac{\pi
   }{8}\right) \log \left(x^2+2 x \sin \left(\frac{\pi
   }{8}\right)+1\right)
\right.  \\  &\quad \left. {}
+\frac{1}{8} \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right) \log
   \left(x^2-2 x \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)+1\right)
\right.  \\  &\quad \left. {}
-\frac{1}{8} \sin
   \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right) \log \left(x^2+2 x \cos \left(\frac{\pi
   }{8}\right)+1\right)
\right.  \\  &\quad \left. {}
+\frac{1}{4} \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right) \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\csc \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right) \left(x-\cos \left(\frac{\pi
   }{8}\right)\right)\right)
\right.  \\  &\quad \left. {}
+\frac{1}{4} \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right) \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\csc \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right) \left(x+\cos \left(\frac{\pi
   }{8}\right)\right)\right)
\right.  \\  &\quad \left. {}
-\frac{1}{4} \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right) \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\sec \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right) \left(x-\sin \left(\frac{\pi
   }{8}\right)\right)\right)
\right.  \\  &\quad \left. {}
-\frac{1}{4} \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right) \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\sec \left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right) \left(x+\sin \left(\frac{\pi
   }{8}\right)\right)\right)\right)  \text{.}
\end{align*}

Produced by a [CAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system).  There are some "simplifications", but they don't shorten the expression much.